# libpng pixel data is in greyscale, need RGBA values

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, libpng, rgba

I have been working with libpng for a few days now. I have been able to load and PNG image and convert it to RGBA8888, for the most part. The main thing that is lacking is color. I can't seem to figure out why libpng reads the data in as greyscale.

I have tried using:

```
    png_set_palette_to_rgb(png_ptr)
```

and

```
    png_set_gray_to_rgb(png_ptr);
```

to no avail. I have reviewed the documentation on libpng a few times now, I must be missing something obvious...

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.1

I tried following this tutorial here, and ended up with the same grey scale image:

http://devcry.heiho.net/html/2015/20150517-libpng.html

To be completely clear, I am on a raspberry pi. I am using Embedded Wizard and its 'externBitmap' feature to dynamically load png images at run-time. Embedded Wizard requires RGBA8888 formatting of pixel data.

Here is the code that I am using to load the image file:

```
    void read_png_file(char* file_name)
    {
    int y;
    png_byte color_type;
    png_byte bit_depth;
    png_byte channels;
    int number_of_passes;
    char header[8];    // 8 is the maximum size that can be checked

    /* open file and test for it being a png */
    FILE *fp = fopen(file_name, "rb");
    if (!fp)
        abort_("[read_png_file] File %s could not be opened for reading", file_name);
    fread(header, 1, 8, fp);
    if (png_sig_cmp(header, 0, 8))
        abort_("[read_png_file] File %s is not recognized as a PNG file", file_name);


    /* initialize stuff */
    png_ptr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!png_ptr)
        abort_("[read_png_file] png_create_read_struct failed");

    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (!info_ptr)
        abort_("[read_png_file] png_create_info_struct failed");

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)))
        abort_("[read_png_file] Error during init_io");

    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);
    png_set_sig_bytes(png_ptr, 8);

    png_read_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    width = png_get_image_width(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    height = png_get_image_height(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    color_type = png_get_color_type(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    bit_depth = png_get_bit_depth(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    channels = png_get_channels(png_ptr, info_ptr);
    
    printf("%i x %i\n", width, height);
    printf("Color type: %d\n", color_type);
    printf("Bit Depth: %d\n", bit_depth);
    printf("Channels: %d\n", channels);
    
    //number_of_passes = png_set_interlace_handling(png_ptr);
    png_read_update_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);


    /* read file */
    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr)))
        abort_("[read_png_file] Error during read_image");

    row_pointers = (png_bytep*) malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        row_pointers[y] = (png_byte*) malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png_ptr,info_ptr));

    //png_set_palette_to_rgb(png_ptr);
    png_read_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

    fclose(fp);
    
    printf("png file read success. Processing file...\n");
}
```

Actual png:
[Actual png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f84XN.png)
[image: icon]

After I decode and attempt displaying:
[After decoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DipV2.jpg)

Edit:
I updated the code with a few more commands:

```
png_set_palette_to_rgb(png_ptr);
if (png_get_valid(png_ptr, info_ptr,PNG_INFO_tRNS)) 
    png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png_ptr);
```

The resulting image is kinda hard to see here, but there are colors now, the image seems like it is being stretched now as only part of the original image is being displayed.:
[stretched with color now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHRBh.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the image is grey, we can't see it. How many channels does it say it has? What is the color type?

Comment: I added the actual and resulting pngs to the original question. libpng reports:
Channels: 1
Bitdepth: 8
Color Type: 3

Comment: I think you need to add `if (png_get_valid(png_ptr, info_ptr,PNG_INFO_tRNS)) png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(png_ptr);` after `png_set_plette(...)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thank you for you help, I have updated the original question with an image and description of what is happening now. I think we are getting closer! Any other ideas on commands that need to be added.

Comment: Not at a computer, but I guess you need to call one of the padXXX() functions now. Or is it `fillXXX()`? Sorry, can't remember.`